# AngularJs - Combine on ng-bind : literal (i18n) + $scope element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to combine labels with elements of `$scope` without success. Any idea if that's possible and how?

What I've tried:

`principalpage.user = 'User'`
`$scope.user= 'Jim'`

`ng-bind="'principalpage.user' | translate {{user}}"`
`ng-bind="{{'principalpage.user' | translate}} {{user}}"`
`ng-bind="'principalpage.user' | translate user"`
`ng-bind="'principalpage.user' | translate 'user'"`

They work good separately but not together.

PD: Used `ng-bind` instead of `{{...}}` for the best practices of 'AngularJS' and because the `{{..}}` showed up when the page is refreshing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, this should do the trick:

```
ng-bind="('principalpage.user' | translate) + ' ' + user"
```

Translate `'principalpage.user'`, then add the user variable behind it.

Comment: Problem is that " principalpage.user = 'User' " is in a i18n folder (i18n/en) and not on the $scope (Forgot to say that)

Comment: So, is it a global variable?

Comment: It's a 'key' used by the filter 'translate' to search on the correspondant 'json' to find the correct value according to the selected language

Comment: Ah, looks like you shouldn't use `{{ }}`. `ng-bind` requires an expression, so it's already parsed as JS.